# Django Fetching Data From DataBase Based on join Using ORM

Tags: django, django-models

I want to join two models as shown below and the join should be Harsha to Bank only(not Bank to Harsha)

model.py

```
class Harsha(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Bank(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(Harsha, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accountnumber = models.BigIntegerField()
    ifsc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bank = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py

```
test = Harsha.objects.all()
test1 = Bank.objects.all() # its working for me but i want join from Harsha table
```

in templates

```
# I want this
{% for tes in test %}
    {{ tes.name }}
    {{ tes.email }}
    {{ tes.bank.accountnumber }}  # how can I get this field
    {{ tes.bank.ifsc }}  # how can I get this field
{% endfor %}

# its working
{% for tes in test1 %}
    {{ tes.user.name }}
    {{ tes.user.email }}
    {{ tes.accountnumber }}
    {{ tes.ifsc }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this(using [**`reverse relationship`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)):

```
{% for tes in test %}
    {{ tes.name }}
    {{ tes.email }}
    {% for bank in tes.bank_set.all %}
    {{ bank.accountnumber }}  
    {{ bank.ifsc }}  
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```